# can't isntall NGINX in a centOS7

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

can you help me with this?

I'm trying to create a container with a centOS 7 and running on it nginx and PHP. this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM remote-host
COPY ./conf/nginx.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
RUN                                                                          \
  yum -y install nginx-1.12.2 --enablerepo=nginx                  && \
  yum -y install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm                  && \
  yum -y install                                                             \
    php71u-fpm                                                               \
    php71u-cli                                                               \
    php71u-mysqlnd                                                           \
    php71u-soap                                                              \
    php71u-xml                                                               \
    php71u-zip                                                               \
    php71u-json                                                              \
    php71u-mcrypt                                                            \
    php71u-mbstring                                                          \
    php71u-zip                                                               \
    php71u-gd                                                                \
     --enablerepo=ius-archive && yum clean all
EXPOSE 80 443
VOLUME /var/www/html /var/log/nginx /var/log/php-fpm /var/lib/php-fpm
COPY ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./bin/start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
CMD /start.sh
```

but when docker start to create it this error appear:

```
Building web
Step 1/9 : FROM remote-host
 ---> 678df95b4f1b
Step 2/9 : COPY ./conf/nginx.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2846848bf7b4
Step 3/9 : RUN                                                                            yum -y install nginx-1.12.2 --enablerepo=nginx                  &&   yum -y install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm                  &&   yum -y install                                                                 php71u-fpm                                                                   php71u-cli                                                                   php71u-mysqlnd                                                               php71u-soap                                                                  php71u-xml                                                                   php71u-zip                                                                   php71u-json                                                                  php71u-mcrypt                                                                php71u-mbstring                                                              php71u-zip                                                                   php71u-gd                                                                     --enablerepo=ius-archive && yum clean all
 ---> Running in 16ffb3c86062
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            4.2 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:01    
CentOS-8 - Base                                 3.5 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:01    
CentOS-8 - Extras                               1.5 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    
CentOS-8 - Extras                               5.4 kB/s | 8.6 kB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - 4.7 kB/s | 2.7 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 -  27 kB/s |  97 kB     00:03    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64  5.1 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64  615 kB/s | 8.3 MB     00:13    
nginx repo                                       52 kB/s |  76 kB     00:01    
All matches were filtered out by modular filtering for argument: nginx-1.12.2
Error: Unable to find a match: nginx-1.12.2
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install nginx-1.12.2 --enablerepo=nginx                  &&   yum -y install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm                  &&   yum -y install                                                                 php71u-fpm                                                                   php71u-cli                                                                   php71u-mysqlnd                                                               php71u-soap                                                                  php71u-xml                                                                   php71u-zip                                                                   php71u-json                                                                  php71u-mcrypt                                                                php71u-mbstring                                                              php71u-zip                                                                   php71u-gd                                                                     --enablerepo=ius-archive && yum clean all' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

why **nginx-1.12.2** cannot be found? also, there is any problem with PHP version?

Comment: You omit most important information: what is `remote-host`?

Comment: is a Service in a docker-compose which is a Centos7 container with other services installed earlier

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here:

- Looks `nginx` also in `https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm`, so you need to install this source first.
- The nginx in this source is `1.16.1`, see this:

  ```
  # yum list | grep nginx
  nginx.x86_64                              1:1.16.1-2.el7                 @epel
  ```

  So, if you really insist on 1.12.2, you will have to find a new source.

The php version is ok, then if you do not care nginx version, a workable minimal `Dockerfile` as next:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN                                                                          \
  yum -y install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm                  && \
  yum -y install nginx-1.16.1                                             && \
  yum -y install                                                             \
    php71u-fpm                                                               \
    php71u-cli                                                               \
    php71u-mysqlnd                                                           \
    php71u-soap                                                              \
    php71u-xml                                                               \
    php71u-zip                                                               \
    php71u-json                                                              \
    php71u-mcrypt                                                            \
    php71u-mbstring                                                          \
    php71u-zip                                                               \
    php71u-gd                                                                \
     --enablerepo=ius-archive && yum clean all
```

Answer (score 1):

> The exact Dockerfile need for this purpose:

<-- language-all: lang-html -->

```
FROM remote-host

LABEL Remarks="This is a Dockerfile for CentOS System"

COPY ./conf/nginx.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo

#Update Software Repository
RUN yum -y install epel-release
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install nginx

EXPOSE 80 443
VOLUME /var/www/html /var/log/nginx /var/log/php-fpm /var/lib/php-fpm
COPY ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./bin/start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
CMD /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```